# Centering axis title relative to the entire plot area in R Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have a horizontal bar chart in Plotly with quite long axis labels and a long x-axis title. I'm using this figure in Shiny so it's width vary depending on the users screen sie. The problem is that on smaller screens the axis title is cut. I want it to be centered relative to the entire plot area instead of the axis to prevent this.

Minimal example:

```
data <- data.frame(
    x = c(0.5, 0.3, 0.1),
    y = c("Long axis label 1", "Long axis label 2", "Long axis label 3")
)

plot_ly(
    data,
    y = ~ y,
    x = ~ x,
    type = "bar"
) %>% layout(
        margin = list(l = 160, r = 20, b = 50, t = 20),
        xaxis = list(title = "Preeeeeeeeeeeeeety long X axis label", tickformat = "%"),
        yaxis = list(title = "Y axis label", tickprefix = "    ", tickwidth = 1, tickcolor = toRGB("white"))

    )
```

How it looks on smaller screens:

[image]

Here's how I would like it to be:

[image]

I've already figured out that I can move the title to the left by adding non breaking spaces like `list(title = "Preeeeeeeeeeeeeety long X axis label&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")` but that's not what I need. Any ideas on how to center it properly?

Answer (score 2):

This is not exacty what you want but is the only way I know. Hope it helps:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

data <- data.frame(
  x = c(0.5, 0.3, 0.1),
  y = c("Long axis label 1", "Long axis label 2", "Long axis label 3")
)

plot_ly(
  data,
  y = ~ y,
  x = ~ x,
  type = "bar"
) %>% layout(
  margin = list(l = 160, r = 20, b = 50, t = 20),
  annotations = list(text = 'Preeeeeeeeeeeeeety long X axis label',
                     font = list(size = 12),
                     showarrow = F,
                     xref = 'paper', x = -0.3,
                     yref = 'paper', y = -0.2))

)
```

[image]

Comment: This code seem not to change anything. I edited my question for better clarity.

Comment: I've edited my answer. It's not exactly what you want but maybe can be useful

Comment: That is useful but title placement still depends on values specified. I need the chart to be responsive, that is to achieve exactly the same effect after resizing.